# MySQL DB Level Selections

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-structures

I have a table wherein users save their answers to certain questions.

For Eg: 
There are 5 question:

- User "A" has selected answer numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 for these 5 questions.
- User "B" has selected answer numbers 1, 4, 2, 4, 1 for these 5 questions.
- User "C" has selected answer numbers 1, 2, 4, 4, 1 for these 5 questions.

User "A" and User "B" have same answers to question numbers: 1, 4 and 5. 
**ie 3 same answers**.

User "A" and User "C" have same answers to question number 1, 2, 4 and 5. 
**ie. 4 same answers**

The mysql query should output me results in following order.

- User "C" - 4 matches
- User "B" - 3 matches

The output should have the maximum matching answers first.

Is it possible to do this at database level. 
The reason I want to do this at database level, is the frontend query asks for selection of user that have atleast 4 matching answers, or atleast 7 matching answers. There are huge number of users.

I am open to creating new data structures to save data in a format, that will make these calculations possible.

Looking forwards towards suggestions and guidance.

Thank You.

There is nothing like a correct answer. Each answer can be a correct answer. Question will be like " Which colour do you Like ", wherein all answers are correct. We need to match number of same answers between a user, and all other users. The results, we want to sort by ones having largest number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

When saving the answers to the db you might consider an additional field that stores the number of correct answers (e.g integer of 4, 5 etc.) which you can later sort on when returning records.

Comment: There is nothing like correct answers. Each answer is a multiple choice question like "Which Colour do You Like". I need to select users selecting the same answer.

Comment: OK if selected answers have distinct associated values why not store this as a single value

Comment: Sorry i meant that each answer is a correct answer for a question. The question itself is something like "Which colour do you Like". Here any answer can be correct. What I am trying to do here, is get 2 users who have the same likes and dislikes. Sorry for the confusion.